# Facebook app fails to load - Content Security Policy "frame-src"

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, content-security-policy

We have a Facebook app that has been around for a long time. It's a page-based app, loading up in an iframe. Of late, it is failing to load, and this error appears in the Chrome console:

```
[Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://edit.ihouseelite.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src *.doubleclick.net *.google.com *.facebook.com www.googleadservices.com *.fbsbx.com".
```

You can see the problem in our test page:

```
https://www.facebook.com/Test-page-1158553550884937/app/451851288205481
```

First - this message starts with "Report Only". Does that mean that this error is not really an error, but perhaps an indication of future problems?

Assuming that it really is an error, how do I fix it? It seems like the CSP is something set by Facebook, so they only permit specific domains to load up in iframes within a Facebook page. Or am I reading that incorrectly? I figured that setting the domain in the App Settings (basic) would adjust the CSP, but it doesn't seem to have done that.  We have a couple thousand customers who are using our app, so I would really like to figure out how to fix this. All suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's a CSP of facebook, it publishes two CSPs: `content-security-policy` and `content-security-policy-report-only`, you can see it in the Dev tool:
[image]

Using CSP in `Report-Only` mode, facebook just test something, there is no real blocking just violation reports sending.
Facebook's CSP cannot be affected just like that, but when creating a legitimate application, facebook should automatically add app's domain to the frame-src directive.

Comment: "facebook should automatically add app's domain to the frame-src directive" - this is what I expected, but it doesn't seem to be doing that, our domain (edit.ihouseweb.com) isn't being added. And although it says "Report Only", it also is blocking our app from being framed in.

Comment: It's possible that your Facebook app hasn't been published yet or hasn't been approved by moderators. Facebook tech support should be asked this question anyway, because without including the application domain in the `frame-src` directive, it will not work on facebook pages.

Comment: Well, I wrote this app several years ago, Facebook seems to make changes that break things fairly often. We actually can't do new installs at this point because accounts have to have 2000 followers to install apps on pages. I'll try to check with tech support.

Comment: A facebook uses the `report-uri` directibe in its CSPs, so they receive the reports about all violations and must respond to them.