# I'm loading a angular app uplaoded on firebase in facebook webview. Getting refused to frame error

Tags: angular, iframe, content-security-policy, facebook-iframe, facebook-webhooks

I'm loading an angular app uploaded on firebase in facebook webview. Getting refused to frame error for both API and view. I have put meta tags in index.html too.

**ERROR**:

HTML Rendor Error

```
[Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://yyyyyyy/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src *.doubleclick.net *.google.com *.facebook.com www.googleadservices.com *.fbsbx.com".

VM346 referer_frame.php:1 [Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://yyyyyyyy/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src *.doubleclick.net *.google.com *.facebook.com www.googleadservices.com *.fbsbx.com".
```

API calling blocked error

```
zone-evergreen.js:2845 Refused to connect to 'https://xxxxxxxx' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I have added following meta tags to index.html

**META TAGS:**
API URL: https://xxxxxx/
Firebase  URL: https://yyyyyy/

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src *.doubleclick.net *.google.com *.facebook.com www.googleadservices.com *.fbsbx.com https://yyyyyy/ frame-src *.doubleclick.net *.google.com *.facebook.com www.googleadservices.com *.fbsbx.com">  
  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'  data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' https://xxxxxx/">
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a CSP which prohibits insert iframes into his pages. The error:

```
[Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://yyyyyyy/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
  "frame-src *.doubleclick.net *.google.com *.facebook.com www.googleadservices.com *.fbsbx.com".
```

belongs this facebook's CSP, this has already been figured out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69230031/facebook-app-fails-to-load-content-security-policy-frame-src).

Please note that this CSP violation presented even before you added the meta tag.
Anyway there is no way to mitigate third-party CSP by adding your own. Your CSP acts inside your iframe, but the main page (*.facebook.com) will follow facebook's CSP.